# Seaborn keeps flipping my rows for multi-graphs

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I'm using Seaborn for some data exploration and am using the catplot functions. When I use `col='something'` to create multiple graphs, I am running into an issue where the variable names of one plot do not match up with another. The colors are the same. I've tried using the `order=list`, but nothing seems to work.

An example would be

```
sns.catplot(x=variable, y=other_variable, data=df, col=something, kind='bar')
```

and I get something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYqQQ.png).

Comment: You could use a dictionary as palette. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46173419/seaborn-change-bar-colour-according-to-hue-name)

Comment: If previous comment did not work, could you add a sample of your dataframe?

Comment: So the colors are the same per column, i.e. if column A on the first graph is the same category as column D on the second graph, they are the same color. Its the actual ordering of the columns I can't get straight. Graph 1 is ordered A,B,C,D and Graph 2 is D,C,B,A

Comment: Please edit your question and add an example using reproducible code. You could try adding the argument `order=['A','B','C','D']`.