# Set color for specific bar in catplot

Tags: python, seaborn, bar-chart, catplot

For the code below I am trying to create a barplot. If the column name in column ACQUISITION_CHANNEL = 'Referral' then the bar should be red else grey.

```
g = sns.catplot(
    data=df, kind="bar",
    x="CITY", y="CUSTOMERS", hue="ACQUISITION_CHANNEL",
    ci="sd", palette=clrs, alpha=.6, height=8
)
g.despine(left=False)
g.set_axis_labels("", "Share Total Customers for each City (%)")
g.legend.set_title("")
```

This is what I have tried so far, but it did not work

```
values = df.Customers
clrs = ['grey' if (x < max(values)) else 'red' for x in values ]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Seaborn - change bar colour according to hue name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46173419/seaborn-change-bar-colour-according-to-hue-name)

Comment: Can you add your input dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a `dict` that maps the values used for the `hue` parameter to matplotlib colours, see the [second example under point plots](http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/categorical.html#point-plots).

```py
df = sns.load_dataset("tips")
palette = {c: "grey" if c != "Male" else "r" for c in df["sex"].unique()}
# {'Female': 'grey', 'Male': 'r'}

g = sns.catplot(
    data=df, 
    kind="bar",
    x="day", 
    y="total_bill", 
    hue="sex",
    ci="sd", 
    palette=palette, 
    alpha=.6, 
)
```

[image]